# where to find "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" for facebook?

Tags: azure, xamarin, oauth, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am using azure facebook authentication for `Xamarin.Android` and i cant find what to put in Valid OAuth redirect URIs field in facebook? thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> what to put in Valid OAuth redirect URIs field in facebook?

Please try to enter `your application URL + /.auth/login/facebook/callback` in the Valid OAuth redirect URIs. [Chapter 2 - Authentication  Social Authentication](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/social/) written by Adrian Hall show the detailed steps to configure&add Authentication to Mobile App, please read it.

[image]

Comment: Hi @MuhammadAwais, if it is helpful, please mark it as answer, which will help others quickly find this thread and solve the similar problem.

Comment: this link is running perfectly on my brower its asks for login now but there is an error with i run m mobile app error" the web page at "xyzlink" might be temporarily down or removed

Comment: Do you mean that login popup does not display as expected when you want to login in mobile app?